# Change card content style on clicking button on card

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, ngfor, mat-card

In my component , i have generated mat-card(which is another component) through *ngFor. There is one button on card on clicking is should style same card elements(which i am able to do.) But if I click the another card button, it should style that one and revert back styles of the previous card to the original style.(Facing issue in this part).
Below is the sample code

Parent component html

```
<div class="ui-lg-3 ui-md-6 ui-g-12" *ngFor="let Obj of fruitList;let i=index;">
    <card-view-mini  [fruit]="Obj" (selectedFruit)="selectedFruit($event)"></card-view-mini>
</div>
```

child component html`"<div><mat-card>
   <span [ngClass]="{'selectedFruit':enableStyle}">{{fruit}}</span>
   <button (click)="changeStyle()">
</mat-card></div>"`

changeStyle() `changeStyle(){
this.enableStyle=true;
}`

Comment: can you share some code ??

Comment: edited the problem and added the code sample

Comment: Try this `this.enableStyle = !this.enableStyle;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have id's for your fruit. 
If so you can do something like this:

`<span [ngClass]="{'selectedCSSClass':fruit.id == selected}">{{fruit}}</span>`

`<button (click)="selected=fruit.id">`

where the first line will check if the selected is equals with the fruit.id
and the button will set the selected with the current fruit.id. 
you don't even need the select function.

Comment: i am able to apply style on the card. I just want applied style on 1st card get reverted when I click on button of second card and style should get applied on second card.

Comment: Yes i understood, and that is what the code should do, have you managed to get the results you wanted?